# C++ Vector Sort String Issue

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

Okay I have a little assignment I need to sort a vector of strings using std::sort but it does not sort any "numbers" above two digest correctly. It is critical I use this API for the assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> Nums = { "1", "5", "34", "3", "6", "12", "21" };
    sort(Nums.begin(), Nums.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < Nums.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << Nums[i] << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Result:

```
1
12
21
3
34
5
6
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Want:

```
1
3
5
6
12
21
34
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the strings numerically, or lexicographically? i.e. should the list start("1", "3", ... ) or ("1", "12", ...)?

Comment: This is using string sort.  If you want to sort them by numeric value, use a custom comparator in the call to `sort`.  More info here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Numerically, should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::sort` is doing exactly what you're asking it to: it's sorting a list of strings in lexicographical order. To sort numerically, you're going to need to pass a custom comparator to `sort` which compares the strings as if they were numbers. For example:

```
std::sort(std::begin(Nums), std::end(Nums)
          [] (const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) {
              return std::stoi(lhs) < std::stoi(rhs);
          });
```

This uses the function `stoi` from the standard library to convert the strings to `int`s for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the same thing in a more simple manner. You have to use custom `comparison` in order to achieve this.

```
bool cmp(string a,string b)
{
     int p=convertToNum(a); //can use custom function or std::stoi
     int q=convertToNum(b); // converting string to integer
     return p<q;
}
sort(Nums.begin(), Nums.end(),cmp);
```